# Js discord bot why dont work prefix?How to decide a problem with discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  MessageEmbed,
  Partials,
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
} = require("discord.js");
const prefix = '!';



const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,],
  partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message],
});


client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot || !msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Обработка команд
  if (cmd === "ping") {
    const pingTime = Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp;
    msg.reply(`Pong! Latency is ${pingTime}ms`);
  }
});



client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

The code seems to be quite simple, it runs online, the '/' commands work, but everything related to command with prefix does not work.  I don’t know what the reason is, I’ve already tried a lot of code options, but nothing helps.  Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the bot to respond to a prefix you'll have to add the `MessageContent` intent to your intents when instantiating a new client.
Example:

```
const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent],
  partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message],
});
```

Don't forget to also enable this option in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/) ([Here](https://umod.org/community/discord/40519-how-to-enable-message-content-intent) is a small tutorial.)

Comment: Thanks works with ```GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent```